# LTE for Integers (ZZ)

Tags: idris

I am (for fun?) trying to work through all of *How To Prove It* in Idris. One of  the properties I will require is total ordering on the integers. Idris already has the [data.ZZ](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Data/ZZ.idr) module providing inductively based integers. I need to add a type similar to Nat's [LTE](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/f925538745a190d69d5c8867f9f423426afa0cab/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L103). I can't seem to convince myself that my implementation is correct (or that LTE is correct for that matter). How do I "check" that the `LTEZZ` data type I'm working on works? How do I check that `(LTE 4 3)` is invalid?

Example code follows:

```
%default total
||| Proof the a is <= b
||| a is the smaller number
||| b is the larger number
data LTEZZ : (a : ZZ) -> (b : ZZ) -> Type where
  ||| Zero is less than any positive
  LTEZero : LTEZZ (Pos Z) (Pos right)
  ||| If both are positive, and n <= m, n+1 <= m+1
  LTEPosSucc : LTEZZ (Pos left) (Pos right) -> LTEZZ (Pos (S left)) (Pos (S right))
  ||| Negative is always less than positive, including zero
  LTENegPos : LTEZZ (NegS left) (Pos right)
  ||| If both are negative and n <= m, n-1 <= m-1
  LTENegSucc: LTEZZ (NegS (S left)) (NegS (S right)) -> LTEZZ (NegS left) (NegS right)

Uninhabited (LTEZZ (Pos n) (NegS m)) where
  uninhabited LTENegPos impossible
Uninhabited (LTEZZ (Pos (S n)) (Pos Z)) where
  uninhabited LTEZero impossible
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, `LTE` turns `Nat`s into a total order as you can see if you follow [this link](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/f925538745a190d69d5c8867f9f423426afa0cab/libs/contrib/Decidable/Order.idr#L66).

But `LTEZZ` does not do what is intended. One of the ways to check it is to prove the properties of a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) using the definition. But for `LTEZZ` as it is you won't be able e.g. to prove reflexivity.

Here is one way of fixing it:

```
data LTEZZ : (a : ZZ) -> (b : ZZ) -> Type where
  ||| Zero is less than any positive
  LTEZero : LTEZZ (Pos Z) (Pos right)
  ||| If both are positive, and n <= m, n+1 <= m+1
  LTEPosSucc : LTEZZ (Pos left) (Pos right) -> LTEZZ (Pos (S left)) (Pos (S right))
  ||| Negative is always less than positive, including zero
  LTENegPos : LTEZZ (NegS left) (Pos right)
  ||| -1 is the greatest negative number
  LTEMinusOne : LTEZZ (NegS left) (NegS Z)
  ||| If both are negative and n <= m, then n-1 <= m-1
  LTENegSucc: LTEZZ (NegS left) (NegS right) -> LTEZZ (NegS (S left)) (NegS (S right))
```

I added the case for `-1` and fixed the `LTENegSucc` case (you want to make arguments *structurally* smaller at every recursive step, just like for `LTEPosSucc`).

Imports and a couple of helper lemmas:

```
import Data.ZZ
import Decidable.Order

%default total

||| A helper lemma treating the non-negative integers.
lteLtezzPos : m `LTE` n -> Pos m `LTEZZ` Pos n
lteLtezzPos LTEZero = LTEZero
lteLtezzPos (LTESucc x) = LTEPosSucc (lteLtezzPos x)

||| A helper lemma treating the negative integers.
lteLtezzNegS : m `LTE` n -> NegS n `LTEZZ` NegS m
lteLtezzNegS LTEZero = LTEMinusOne
lteLtezzNegS (LTESucc x) = LTENegSucc (lteLtezzNegS x)
```

Reflexivity:

```
||| `LTEZZ` is reflexive.
ltezzRefl : z `LTEZZ` z
ltezzRefl {z = (Pos n)} = lteLtezzPos lteRefl
ltezzRefl {z = (NegS n)} = lteLtezzNegS lteRefl
```

Transitivity:

```
||| `LTEZZ` is transitive.
ltezzTransitive : a `LTEZZ` b -> b `LTEZZ` c -> a `LTEZZ` c
ltezzTransitive LTEZero LTEZero = LTEZero
ltezzTransitive LTEZero (LTEPosSucc _) = LTEZero
ltezzTransitive (LTEPosSucc x) (LTEPosSucc y) = LTEPosSucc (ltezzTransitive x y)
ltezzTransitive LTENegPos LTEZero = LTENegPos
ltezzTransitive LTENegPos (LTEPosSucc x) = LTENegPos
ltezzTransitive LTEMinusOne LTENegPos = LTENegPos
ltezzTransitive LTEMinusOne LTEMinusOne = LTEMinusOne
ltezzTransitive (LTENegSucc x) LTENegPos = LTENegPos
ltezzTransitive (LTENegSucc x) LTEMinusOne = LTEMinusOne
ltezzTransitive (LTENegSucc x) (LTENegSucc y) = LTENegSucc (ltezzTransitive x y)
```

Antisymmetry:

```
||| `LTEZZ` is antisymmetric.
ltezzAntisymmetric : a `LTEZZ` b -> b `LTEZZ` a -> a = b
ltezzAntisymmetric LTEZero LTEZero = Refl
ltezzAntisymmetric (LTEPosSucc x) (LTEPosSucc y) =
  rewrite (posInjective (ltezzAntisymmetric x y)) in Refl
ltezzAntisymmetric LTEMinusOne LTEMinusOne = Refl
ltezzAntisymmetric (LTENegSucc x) (LTENegSucc y) =
  rewrite (negSInjective (ltezzAntisymmetric x y)) in Refl
```

Totality:

```
||| `LTEZZ` is total.
ltezzTotal : (a : ZZ) -> (b : ZZ) -> Either (LTEZZ a b) (LTEZZ b a)
ltezzTotal (Pos k) (Pos j) with (order {to=LTE} k j)
  ltezzTotal (Pos k) (Pos j) | (Left pf) = Left $ lteLtezzPos pf
  ltezzTotal (Pos k) (Pos j) | (Right pf) = Right $ lteLtezzPos pf
ltezzTotal (Pos k) (NegS j) = Right LTENegPos
ltezzTotal (NegS k) (Pos j) = Left LTENegPos
ltezzTotal (NegS k) (NegS j) with (order {to=LTE} k j)
  ltezzTotal (NegS k) (NegS j) | (Left pf) = Right $ lteLtezzNegS pf
  ltezzTotal (NegS k) (NegS j) | (Right pf) = Left $ lteLtezzNegS pf
```